# how can i make react render the price in the first line of fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an invoice form. I've the fields state that handle the state `inputText` to add one. When I press `ajouter`, so when I write the ID product react get it from my database but when I want to put the price got into first line it render it in the second line of form

Here is the code :

```
const Facture = () => {
  //State
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([
    {
      nomenclature: null,
      qte: null,
    },
  ]);
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ id: "", price: "" }]);

  // Function:
  const handleChange = (i, event) => {
    let newFormValues = [...fields];
    newFormValues[i][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setId(event.target.value);
    setFields(newFormValues);
    console.log(newFormValues);
  };
  const removeFormFields = (i) => {
    let newFormValues = [...fields];
    newFormValues.splice(i, 1);
    setFields(newFormValues);
  };
  function Add() {
    let newField = { nomenclature: "", qte: "" };
    setFields([...fields, newField]);
    console.log(fields);
  }
  // try {
  //   const response = await axios.get(
  //     `http://localhost:3001/api/product/${fields.nomenclature}`
  //   );
  //   const fetchedData = response.data;
  //   setData(fetchedData);
  // } catch (error) {
  //   console.error("Failed to fetch data:", error);
  // }
  //   useEffect(()=>{

  //   },[]);
  // const fetchData = async () => {
  //   try {
  //     const responseArray = await Promise.all(fields.map(async (field) => {
  //       const url = `http://localhost:3001/api/product/${field.nomenclature}`;
  //       const response = await axios.get(url);
  //       const responseData= response.data;
  //       setData((prev)=>[...prev,responseData]);
  //       console.log("this is the data" ,data);
  //       console.log(response.data);
  //       return response.data;
  //     }));

  //   } catch (error) {
  //     console.error("Failed to fetch data:", error);
  //   }
  // };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const responseArray = await Promise.all(
          fields.map(async (field) => {
            const url = `http://localhost:3001/api/product/${field.nomenclature}`;
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            const responseData = response.data;
            setData((prev) => [...prev, responseData]);
            console.log("this is the data", data);
            console.log(response.data);
          })
        );

        // Handle the responseArray if needed
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [fields]);
  return (
    <ComponentSkeleton>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                required
                id={`nom-${index}`}
                name="nomenclature"
                label="Nomenclature Produit"
                fullWidth
                autoComplete="shipping country"
                variant="outlined"
                value={field.nomenclature}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e)}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
              <TextField
                id={`prix-${index}`}
                name="prix"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="prix"
                InputProps={{
                  readOnly: true,
                }}
                key={index - 1}
                value={data[index].price}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
              <TextField
                required
                id={`qte-${index}`}
                name="qte"
                label="Qte"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                value={field.qte}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e)}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
              <TextField
                readOnly
                id={`total-${index}`}
                name="total"
                label="Prix total"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                // value={flow.amountConsumed}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="delete"
                color="error"
                onClick={() => removeFormFields(index)}
              >
                <DeleteIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Grid>
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}

      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          startIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon color="white" />}
          onClick={Add}
          size="small"
        >
          Ajouter
        </Button>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={3}></Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <center>
          <b>Total</b>
        </center>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        {/* <b>{sum}</b> */}
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={3}></Grid>

      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <center>
          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            color="success"
            size="large"
            // onClick={fetchData}
          >
            Valider
          </Button>
        </center>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="error" size="large">
          Annuler
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </ComponentSkeleton>
  );
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwxU4.png)